# Create JAVA method to return multiple ArrayLists of different type

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a method to loop and iterate through an ArrayList of type "MenuItem" from a text file which in a separate class creates objects such as Entrees, Sides, Salads, and Desserts and all objects are added to the ArrayList of MenuItem. In the method I am trying to separate each object type into their own separate ArrayList when the instance of that object is read. How can I go about returning each separate ArrayList in the method?

```
public MenuManager(String dishesFile) {

        ArrayList<MenuItem> menu = FileManager.readItems(dishesFile);

        arrayMenu(menu);

    }

    public static ArrayList<MenuItem> arrayMenu(ArrayList<MenuItem> menus) {
        ArrayList<MenuItem> menu = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

        ArrayList<Entree> entr = new ArrayList<Entree>();
        ArrayList<Side> side = new ArrayList<Side>();
        ArrayList<Salad> salad = new ArrayList<Salad>();
        ArrayList<Dessert> dess = new ArrayList<Dessert>();

        for(MenuItem menuArr : menu) {
            if(menuArr instanceof Entree) {
                entr.add(new Entree(menuArr.getName(), menuArr.getDescription(), menuArr.getCalories(), menuArr.getPrice()));
            }
            else if(menuArr instanceof Side) {
                side.add(new Side(menuArr.getName(), menuArr.getDescription(), menuArr.getCalories(), menuArr.getPrice()));
            }
            else if(menuArr instanceof Salad) {
                salad.add(new Salad(menuArr.getName(), menuArr.getDescription(), menuArr.getCalories(), menuArr.getPrice()));
            }
            else if(menuArr instanceof Dessert) {
                dess.add(new Dessert(menuArr.getName(), menuArr.getDescription(), menuArr.getCalories(), menuArr.getPrice()));
            }


        }
        return menu;

    }
```

Comment: Wrap them in an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Collections;    
import java.util.List;    

public class SortedMenuItems {

    private final List<Entree> entr;
    private final List<Side> side;
    private final List<Salad> salad;
    private final List<Dessert> dess;

    public SortedMenuItems(List<Entree> entr, List<Side> side, List<Salad> salad, List<Dessert> dess) {
        this.entr = Collections.unmodifiableList(entr)
        this.side= Collections.unmodifiableList(side)
        this.salad = Collections.unmodifiableList(salad)
        this.dess = Collections.unmodifiableList(dess)
    }

    public List<Entree> getEntrees() {
        return entr;
    }

    public List<Side> getSides() {
        return side;
    }

    public List<Salad> getSalads() {
        return salad;
    }

    public List<Desert> getDeserts() {
        return dess;
    }

}
```

And then change the return statement of `arrayMenu()` to...

```
return new SortedMenuItems(entr, side, salad, dess);
```